# Inserting images in word using C# between the sentence

Tags: c#, image, ms-word, insertion

I have a MS word file which has some sentences and  I need to insert some images in between the lines. When I am using the `AddPicture` method in `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` I am able to insert the image but not at a particular position.

I did not find any method to insert other than `AddPicture` to insert an image into existing word file. **I am trying to insert an image after a particular line after apple there should an image of apple**.

Here I am creating a paragraph and trying to add the image. This is my initial file:

[image]

This contains paragraphs containing the words apple, mango, and grape.

This is the output of my code (below)

[image]

The image should be inserted after the apple line
Required output:

[Required Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9er3H.png)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Metadata;
using Word =Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.IO;
namespace ConsoleApp2 
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Word.Application ap = new Word.Application();
            Word.Document document = ap.Documents.Open(@"C:\Users\ermcnnj\Desktop\Doc1.docx");
            //document.InlineShapes.AddPicture(@"C:\Users\ermcnnj\Desktop\apple.png");
            String read = string.Empty;
            List<string> data = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < document.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
            {
                string temp = document.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.Trim();
                if (temp != string.Empty && temp.Contains("Apple"))
                {
                    var pPicture = document.Paragraphs.Add();
                    pPicture.Format.SpaceAfter = 10f;
                    document.InlineShapes.AddPicture(@"C:\Users\ermcnnj\Desktop\apple.png", Range: pPicture.Range);
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

The above is the code I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippet illustrates how this can be done. Note that. for the sake of clarity, it's simplified to set only the text to be found - there are a lot of additional properties that might need to be specified; read up on the `Find` functionality in Word's Language Reference.

If a search term is found, the `Range` associated with `Find` changes to the found term and further action can be taken. In this case, a new (empty) paragraph is inserted after the found term. (The question specifies that the term is the entire content of a paragraph, so that's what this example assumes!) The `Range` is then moved to this new paragraph and the `InlineShape` inserted.

Note how the graphic is assigned to an `InlineShape` object. If anything needs to be done to this object, work with the object variable `ils`.

```
Word.Application ap = new Word.Application();
Word.Document document = ap.Documents.Open(@"C:\Users\ermcnnj\Desktop\Doc1.docx");

Word.Range rng = document.Content;
Word.Find wdFind = rng.Find;

wdFind.Text = "apple";
bool found = wdFind.Execute();

if (found)
{
    rng.InsertAfter("\n");
    rng.MoveStart(Word.WdUnits.wdParagraph, 1);
    Word.InlineShape ils = rng.InlineShapes.AddPicture(@"C:\Test\avatar.jpg", false, true, rng);
 }
```